# razor Html.RadioButton position into image

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, razor

I need an advice on how to approach to the task that requires to format html page.
Lets say I have an image as a circle and I need to place 7 radiobuttons around it. 
Theoretically it is possible to accomplish it by using dev object, but it seems to me this way is to complicated to do. Is there any other way to place radiobuttons around circle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/Le4nz2L5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style class="cp-pen-styles">
        html,
        body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        }
        body {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        .main,
        .container {
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .main {
        background-color: #B81365;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 50;
        }

        .main .title {
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fafafa;
        }

        .container {
        z-index: 10;
        }

        .plate {
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:13px;
        height:13px;
        text-align:center;
        }
        .main + .container .plate:nth-of-type(1) {
        top: -180%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(2) {
        top: -130%;
        right: -120%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(3) {
        right: -170%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(4) {
        right: -120%;
        bottom: -130%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(5) {
        bottom: -180%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(6) {
        bottom: -130%;
        left: -140%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(7) {
        left: -190%;
        }
        .container .plate:nth-of-type(8) {
        top: -130%;
        left: -140%;
        }
    </style></head><body>
    <center>
    based on:<a href="http://codepen.io/Oka/pen/BNjwNz">Colin Hall-Coates codepen</a>
    </center>
    <label class='main' for='check'>
        <div class='title'>
            <i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
        </div>
    </label>
    <div class='container'>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
        <a class='plate' href='#'>
        <input type="radio"></input>
        </a>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly that I was looking for.